# Content falls beneath navigation bar when embedded in custom container view controller and UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, autolayout, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am using UISplitViewController and UIContainerView as shown in fig.

[image]

Code for displaying this is:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplitContainerVC"];
```

It am Pretty sure auto layouts for container view are accurate.

Why my content view (search bar etc) is beneath `UINavigation bar`? Please see attached fig.

[image]

I have removed following code and its work fine:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return NO;
}
```

But i need this above code. What's an issue behind this?

Comment: Seeing the exact same thing minus the container view.  Also have a search bar at the top.  Wondering if that is meaningful.  Will play with it down that path.

Comment: Are you using something like this :
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
ScrollPositionTop is causing an issue.

Comment: I actually got stuff working by removing and re-adding the UISearchBar and turned off "Adjust scroll view insets" for the view controller in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in iOS 8 you should use preferredDisplayMode. As `shouldHideViewController` is deprecated in iOS8.

To show both view controllers in portrait mode do the following:

```
self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
```

Hope this helps!